# Unity2D & CSharp: MSBuild process could not be started

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, msbuild, 2d

I'm trying to build my first game in Unity 2D.
**OS: Windows 10**

I reached the moment where I'm supposed to program the controls for a character.

The code:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpHeight;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            GetComponend<RigidBody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, jumpHeight);
        }

    }
}
```

Trying to create a build ends with this error text:

**> Build failed. MSBuild process could not be started**

Please have a look at the screen shot below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7cXj.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please add the code from your image as inline code to this question and use the appropriate edit tools to highlight the received warning.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: You have a typo. Use `GetComponent` instead of `GetComponend`.

Comment: Additionally, if the namespace `UnityEngine` fails to load, try restarting your development environment or reload the project.

Comment: Fixed to "GetComponent" thanks.
But the problem still occurs

Comment: Do you see that same error once you save and return to Unity?